# How to get the next item in C# List?

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have list of tests for a given job.

I have to do a start the test and monitor its status. on completion I have to start the next test.

I hope to store in a List to hold the Test information. on completion of the test, I need to get the next .

Please advise me how to solve this issue.

Code sample as follows.

```
if (myDocument != null)
{
    myDocument.DocumentStatusChanged += new EventHandler<DocumentStatusEventArgs> 
        (myDocument_DocumentStatusChanged);

    StartJob();
}

....
....

void mDocument_DocumentStatusChanged(object sender, DocumentStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == DocumentStatus.Idel)
    {
        StartJob();
    }
}
```

In the StartJob function, I have loop though each item in the list.

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any other way you're using it?
Because if not, a [Queue](http://www.dotnetperls.com/queue) may be what you're looking for.
In that case, you would simply call `myQueue.Dequeue();` to get the next in the list.